# Why does gcc push %rbx at the beginning of main?

Tags: gcc, assembly

The latest version of gcc is producing assembly that doesn't make sense to me.  I compiled the code using no optimization; but, some parts of this code don't make sense, even with no optimization.

Here is the C source:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

   int main()
   {
     int a = 1324;
     int b = 5657;
     int difference = 9876;
     int printf_answer = 2221;

     difference = a - b;

     printf_answer = printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, difference);

     return difference;
   }
```

It produces this assembly:

```
    .file   "exampleIML-1b.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%d + %d = %d\n"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $24, %rsp
    movl    $1324, -32(%rbp)
    movl    $5657, -28(%rbp)
    movl    $9876, -24(%rbp)
    movl    $2221, -20(%rbp)
    movl    -28(%rbp), %eax
    movl    -32(%rbp), %edx
    movl    %edx, %ecx
    subl    %eax, %ecx
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    movl    %eax, -24(%rbp)
    movl    $.LC0, %eax
    movl    -24(%rbp), %ecx
    movl    -28(%rbp), %edx
    movl    -32(%rbp), %ebx
    .cfi_offset 3, -24
    movl    %ebx, %esi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    %eax, -20(%rbp)
    movl    -24(%rbp), %eax
    addq    $24, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Several things don't make sense:

(1) Why are we pushing %rbx?  What is in %rbx that needs to be saved?

(2) Why are we moving %edx to %ecx before subtracting?  What doesn't it just do `sub %eax, %edx`?

(3) Similarly, why the move from %ecx back to %eax before storing the value?

(4) The compiler is putting the variable a in memory location -32(%rbp).  Unless I'm adding wrong, isn't -32(%rbp) equal to the stack pointer?  Shouldn't all local variables be stored at values *less than* the current stack pointer?

I'm using this version of gcc:

[eos17:~/Courses/CS451/IntelMachineLanguage]$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC)

Comment: You are asking: I did compile with optimization off. Why did gcc produce unoptimized code? -1.

Comment: I disagree. Things like storing local variables in memory when they all fit in registers is unoptimized.  It makes sense why a compiler looking at code line-by-line would write assembly that way. In contrast, I don't see why a compilier, even in an unoptimized mode, perform a move before and after the subtract?

Comment: No, that's just your personal interpretation of "unoptimized". For gcc it's just the simplest way of generating code - always using the same registers for operands completely avoids any need for a register allocator, even if it introduces unnecessary moves. The same goes for the `push/pop rbx` - when optimizing, gcc is actually smart enough to recognize that preserving registers through main is not needed

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
GCC dictates how the stack is used. Contract between caller and callee on x86:

    * after call instruction:
          o %eip points at first instruction of function
          o %esp+4 points at first argument
          o %esp points at return address 
    * after ret instruction:
          o %eip contains return address
          o %esp points at arguments pushed by caller
          o called function may have trashed arguments
          o %eax contains return value (or trash if function is void)
          o %ecx, %edx may be trashed
          o %ebp, %ebx, %esi, %edi must contain contents from time of call 
    * Terminology:
          o %eax, %ecx, %edx are "caller save" registers
          o %ebp, %ebx, %esi, %edi are "callee save" registers
```

The main function is like any other function in this context. gcc decided to use `ebx` for intermediate calculations, so it preserves its value.

Comment: Thanks.  I should have seen the use of ebx.

Comment: Specifically, I should have noticed that the compiler used %ebx when setting up the parameters to the call for printf.

Comment: The interesting thing is that gcc is loading the variable from memory into %ebx, then moving it to %esi.  Previous versions of gcc (i.e., the one we used last semester) loaded the data directly from memory into %esi (even when not optimizing).

Comment: Yes. As you compiled it with no optimization, the code is really not efficient. So, probably the '-O2' code would be much readable

Comment: The code with -O2 is actually optimized too much for the purpose of the assignment.  With -O2, the compiler does the subtraction and initializes the variable with the result (i.e., no sub instruction), and it keeps all the variables in registers (i.e., no memory accesses).

Answer (score 5):

By default gcc compiles with optimization disabled, which is the case here, apparently.

You need to enable it with one of the optimization switches (e.g. `-O2` or `-O3`).

Then you will not see redundant and seemingly meaningless things.

As for `rbx`, it has to be preserved because that's what the calling conventions require. Your function modifies it (`movl    -32(%rbp), %ebx`), so it has to be saved and restored explicitly.

Comment: Doh!   I should have seen the use of %ebx.  Thanks.